# Using HangFire without any Dashboard

Tags: sqlite, asp.net-core, hangfire

I am using Hangfire.AspNetCore with [ASP.NET Core v1.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/06/27/announcing-net-core-1-0/).

My Database is [SqlLite](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/netcore/new-db-sqlite.html).

As far as I found, there is no proper SQLite driver for hangfire for .NET Core.

So, I decided to work without any dashboard.

So, what I have configured is like the following:

In **Startup.cs**, in `ConfigureServices` method

```
services.AddHangfire(configuration => {});
```

And in `Configure` method, I am using this

```
app.UseHangfireServer();
```

But I am getting the next error:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Hangfire.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: JobStorage.Current property value has not been initialized. You must set it before using Hangfire Client or Server API.
```

[image]

I don't need dashboard, so I did not configured dashboard.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The error is telling you that you have not configured a job storage provider.  It's got nothing to do with the dashboard.  Even without the dashboard you must have a storage provider.

There is in-memory storage available via Nuget called `Hangfire.MemoryStorage` that you can use if you don't require persistent storage for your background jobs.